# how come python child class doesn't have to give parent parameters?

Tags: python, inheritance, parameters

I don't understand how come child class can be initialized without passing (in the constructor) required parameter to parent class.

This code is based on a question from an exam. I tried the Classes docs for python 3.4.7 and didn't find the answer there or by googling.

```
>>> class parent:
    def __init__(self, param):
        self.v1 = param


>>> class child(parent):
    def __init__(self, param):
        self.v2 = param


>>> obj = child(11)
>>> print(obj.v2)
11
>>> obj = parent()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    obj = parent()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'param'
>>>
```

I expect the line `obj = child(11)` to raise an exception because the child constructor doesn't pass the parameter to parent constructor. the parent cannot be constructed without this parameter.

EDIT: some comments here say that child never calls parent during initialization, and I would like to learn more about this because I am used to the idea of parent being initialized when child is initialized. so if someone can refer me to where it is explained this would answer my question. can't seem to find it on my own.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super

Comment: Why should it raise an exception? You don't call the parent init at all.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I don't understand how this is relevant to my question. can you explain?

Comment: @DanielRoseman How come I don't call the parent constructor when inheriting it?

Comment: If you want the subclass to call the parent constructor, you have to do it by calling super()

Comment: Because that's not how Python works. As the above comment notes, if you want to call the parent method, whether in init or any other method, you have to do so explicitly.

Comment: @DanielRoseman can you refer me to an explanation of how exactly this works in python? I can't find one on google. I mean an explanation of how inheritance works without initializing the parent, not an explanation of how to call the parent which I know already.

Comment: New class instances are actually created by [`__new__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__), `__init__()` is invoked after `__new__()`, to customize the newly created object, but it's not required to actually perform anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a method in a derived class *overrides* the corresponding method in its parent class.  So when `child.__init__` is called, `parent.__init__` is not called.

In this situation it is the responsibility of the programmer to ensure that `child.__init__` initialises the instance correctly.

If `parent.__init__` must also be executed, it must be invoked explicitly.

```
class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self, param):
        self.v2 = param
        super().__init__()
```

If the superclass's `__init__` method expects arguments, they must be provided via `super`:

```
class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self, param1, param2):
        self.v2 = param2
        super().__init__(param1)
```

It's possible to call the parent method directly, rather than via `super`:

```
class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self, param1, param2):
        self.v2 = param2
        Parent.__init__(param1)
```

but `super` better handles complicated inheritance graphs, so programmers often use `super` to avoid having to change the code later.

Raymond Hettinger's article [Super Considered Super](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) discusses `super` at length.

Comment: Thanks! great answer. I upvoted the answer but I'm too new so it doesn't show.